# Why not use Red Woman to take down King's Landing?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

This is about the series - [Game Of Thrones](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/).

> They show that the Red Woman can use magical powers to infiltrate into Renly Baratheon's quarters and kill him with quite the ease. She doesn't fight the guards, she bypasses them in her "shadow" form and heads directly for Renly.

If that is the case, why does Stannis Baratheon not use her to sneak up and take out all the key players of King's Landing and claim his throne?

Comment: *All* the key players?  For the Baratheon/Lannister children that is Joffrey, Myrcella and Tommen.  Her 'blood sacrifice' from Stannis was apparently good for 3 deaths, and weakened him so much that she dare not use more of his blood (and went looking for other sons of kings for more).  For that reason I think they had to make some hard choices.

Comment: In ASoIaF magic always comes with a high price. See also: [he called for his wife, Nissa Nissa, and asked her to bare her breast. He drove his sword into her living heart, her soul combining with the steel of the sword, creating Lightbringer, the Red Sword of Heroes.](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Azor_Ahai)

Answer (score 19):

Several reasons:

1. Unlike the Baratheon/Tyrell alliance, there is no *single* person that could be assassinated and have any lasting effect. Kill Joffrey? He still has an heir. Kill Tyrion? Any number of commanders loyal to the Lannisters can rise to the cause. So on and so forth. Kill Cersei? Tyrion and the realm would've thanked him.
2. Unlike the Baratheon/Tyrell alliance, this was a siege. Even if you disrupted the command structure, you'd still have huge walls you'd have to scale. For the assassination be of any help in a siege it must lead to a complete surrender. No single target exists for such a scenario, and you'd have to kill multiple key people.
3. Creating the "shadow babies" takes a great toll out of Stannis. The one he created (two in the books) greatly weakened him. There was no way he'd be able to create enough of them to help him win King's Landing.
4. Stannis purposely left out Melisandre from the assault on King's Landing in fear that men might call it *her* victory and not his.

Comment: I remember one of the shadow creatures killed Renly, I don't remember the other one who was killed by it?

Comment: @JudgeDredd the other one killed Ser Penrose (book only) castellan of Storm's End.

Comment: @SystemDown She clearly says in S2E03, `I can only request god of fire, I cannot command`. So she cannot kill the person at her will, She can try, but she doesn't guarantee that something will absolutely happen.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in 3x03, in the conversation between Stannis and Melissandre:

> Stannis: I want Joffrey dead. I want Robb Stark dead. Make me another
> son.
>
> Melissandre: I cannot.
>
> Stannis:  Why?
>
> Melissandre: You don't have the strength. It would kill you.
>
> Stannis:  I'm not so easily killed. Men have been trying for years. I
> want you.
>
> Melissandre: Your fires burn low, my king. There is another way. A
> better way.

And then she undertakes the mission to get Gendry. She says that the solution lies in sacrifices, which they try till the very end.